# How to clear the cache of an asp.net application from another asp.net application on the same server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Got a bit of an odd problem. Here goes:

I have two ASP.NET applications: A web app and a web service app.

Information arriving via the webservice effects data in the database used by the web app.

One particular bit of data controls items in a drop down menu - when the data is altered in the app it can call:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove
```

but I now need to clear the cache in the web service as i can recieve messages which update that information.

Can anyone recommend a way of doing this?

Comment: [See this website for a useful cache helper class](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/10/c-cache-helper-class/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cache invalidation can be hard. Off the top of my head I can think of 3 solutions of varying complexity which may or may not work for you.

First, you could write a web service for the web app that the web service app calls to invalidate the cache.  This is probably the hardest.

Second, you could have the web service app write a "dirty" flag in the database that the web app could check before it renders the drop down menu.  This is the route I would go.

Third, you could simply stop caching that particular data.

Comment: in the end...we stopped caching it! We implemented the second but we ended up dropping that whole way of doing things - thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could have a web method whose sole purpose is to clear the cache.

```
var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(clearCacheURL);
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

// receive the response and return it as function result
var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the cache with an expiry time.

> Cache.Insert("DSN", connectionString, null,
>   DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

[Cache.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try SQL Dependency. It will trigger an event when the table you have subscribed has any changes.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events